# Is it possible that multiple location is shown on map,but without using MapView?

Tags: android, google-maps

I think using a mapview is just like using an ox cleaver to kill a chicken for only for only display a few location on the map.

can `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`   do this, or some other method?

Or if it is not possible, then how can I show multiple location markers on the mapView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google Maps' static image.

Just call this [api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Usage) methods and download image.

[For Example this Image shows static Image](http://maps.google.com/staticmap?zoom=12&size=320x80&maptype=mapmaker-roadmap&key=ABQIAAAAUyuOEovY31oCjjRxyc7GpxQ5HUt9vr0tRXgi4D41-GoQUL3LzRS2QGQ8pLU6VMhoS-pf8XKV1qerRQ&sensor=false&center=31.463495269236937,74.31926161050797&markers=31.463495269236937,74.31926161050797)

you can add multiple location to the address separated by `"|"` (bar symbol) for both `center` and `marker` params

Comment: thank you for your answer
static image is one of the choice, but it is not convenience for user, is there another way?

Comment: As for I know, their is no other way.